# three js normalMap repeat

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I have a mesh with normalMap loaded:
[image]

but the normal map did not cover all the surface.
UVs are correctly set to cover all the surface with texture.

Is there any configuration to force normal map repeating?
material.normalMap.repeat.set( x, x ); do not make any difference.

If i switch normalMap to BumpMap or diffuse map "map", it is loaded correctly.

Code:

```
child.material.normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./js/models/asteroids/big/10035-normal.jpg' );
child.material.normalMap.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
///child.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Tip - Do not set `child.material.needsUpdate = true;`. The loader sets it for you. You risk setting it before the material finishes loading.

Comment: i am experiencing the same thing.. seems like setting the repeat doesn't make a difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
child.material.normalMap.wrapS = child.material.normalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```